# TCP Reno Window Size drops to 0

Tags: tcp

I'm working on a task on comparing TCP Tahoe and Reno.

Tahoe drops the window size to 0 every time it detects packet loss, that is clear. However, when I plot my window size for Reno, it does fast recovery sometimes ( as expected, so the window size drops to the current threshold) but other times it drops the size to 0 and does slow start.

Why is this? I thought Reno always did fast recovery?

Answer (score 0):

TCP Reno is not great at handling multiple packet losses and in such cases will need to RTO, and I'm guessing that this is what you see.